# Spring Cloud Stream consume from multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to consume from multiple Apache Kafka topics using Spring Cloud Stream.
After consuming the messages must be processed by separate funсtions:

- topic1 - processed by function pricesProcessor
- topic2 - processed by function pricesProcessorV3

Settings

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  kafka:
    jaas:
      enabled: true
    properties:
      security:
        protocol: "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
      sasl:
        mechanism: PLAIN
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="client" password="client-secret";
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: pricesProcessor;pricesProcessorV3
      #definition: pricesProcessor
      #definition: pricesProcessorV3
    stream:
      bindings:
        pricesProcessor-in-0:
          destination: topic1
          group: ms-pos-prices-provider-v1
        pricesProcessor-out-0:
          destination: topic1.pretty
        pricesProcessorV3-in-0:
          destination: topic2
          group: ms-pos-prices-provider-v3
        pricesProcessorV3-out-0:
          destination: topic2.pretty
      kafka:
        bindings:
          pricesProcessor-in-0:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                value:
                  deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
          pricesProcessor-out-0:
            producer:
              configuration:
                value:
                  serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
          pricesProcessorV3-out-0:
            producer:
              configuration:
                value:
                  serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
          pricesProcessorV3-in-0:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                value:
                  deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:19093, localhost:29093, localhost:39093
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

There is two problems.
The problem one is that messages from topic1 aren't consuming. Messages from topic2 are consuming as usual.
There is the WARN in application log: "The following subscribed topics are not assigned to any members: [ru.bristol.prices]" - I don't understand why

The second problem is that SCS ignores names of the consumer groups that i've set: "group: ms-pos-prices-provider-v1" and "group: ms-pos-prices-provider-v3"
The only one consumer group appears in Kafka and name of the consumer group is equal application name.

As I understand it's possible to read from multiple Kafka topic
But something goes wrong, please help.